# Spring6 how to configure apache http async client in Resttemplate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I was referring the below code from a repository(https://github.com/springframeworkguru/mssc-brewery-client/blob/apache-client/src/main/java/guru/springframework/msscbreweryclient/web/config/NIORestTemplateCustomizer.java) for learning purpose. Where config client is using **Restemplate** to call api which will be build using dependency injection. And there is another class BlockingRestTemplateCustomizer which creates the configuration for resttemplate builder.

But according to the below code how it works and what if BlockingRestTemplateCustomizer bean is created first and then BreweryClient bean is created then as BlockingRestTemplateCustomizer has customize method which expects Resttemplate as dependency?. Whether this will throw exception? and how exactly RestTemplateCustomizer , Resttemplate and RestTemplateBuilder are related(asking this to understand better)?.

And also how to configure the `apache-async-htttpclient` for `Resttemplate` with connection pool as `HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory` is not there as part of spring 6.

**BreweryClient.java**

```
import guru.springframework.msscbreweryclient.web.model.BeerDto;
import guru.springframework.msscbreweryclient.web.model.CustomerDto;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * Created by jt on 2019-04-23.
 */
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "sfg.brewery", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
@Component
public class BreweryClient {

    public final String BEER_PATH_V1 = "/api/v1/beer/";
    public final String CUSTOMER_PATH_V1 = "/api/v1/customer/";
    private String apihost;

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public BreweryClient(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();
    }

    public BeerDto getBeerById(UUID uuid){
        return restTemplate.getForObject(apihost + BEER_PATH_V1 + uuid.toString(), BeerDto.class);
    }

    public URI saveNewBeer(BeerDto beerDto){
        return restTemplate.postForLocation(apihost + BEER_PATH_V1, beerDto);
    }

    public void updateBeer(UUID uuid, BeerDto beerDto){
        restTemplate.put(apihost + BEER_PATH_V1  + uuid, beerDto);
    }

    public void deleteBeer(UUID uuid){
        restTemplate.delete(apihost + BEER_PATH_V1 + uuid );
    }

    public void setApihost(String apihost) {
        this.apihost = apihost;
    }

    public CustomerDto getCustomerById(UUID customerId) {
        return restTemplate.getForObject(apihost+ CUSTOMER_PATH_V1 + customerId.toString(), CustomerDto.class);
    }

    public URI saveNewCustomer(CustomerDto customerDto) {
        return  restTemplate.postForLocation(apihost + CUSTOMER_PATH_V1, customerDto);
    }

    public void updateCustomer(UUID customerId, CustomerDto customerDto) {
        restTemplate.put(apihost + CUSTOMER_PATH_V1 + customerId, customerDto);
    }

    public void deleteCustomer(UUID customerId) {
        restTemplate.delete(apihost + CUSTOMER_PATH_V1 + customerId);
    }
}
```

**BlockingRestTemplateCustomizer.java**

```
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultConnectionKeepAliveStrategy;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateCustomizer;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

/**
 * Created by jt on 2019-08-08.
 */
@Component
public class BlockingRestTemplateCustomizer implements RestTemplateCustomizer {

    public ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory(){
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        connectionManager.setMaxTotal(100);
        connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);

        RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig
                .custom()
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(3000)
                .setSocketTimeout(3000)
                .build();

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients
                .custom()
                .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                .setKeepAliveStrategy(new DefaultConnectionKeepAliveStrategy())
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                .build();

        return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
    }

    @Override
    public void customize(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(this.clientHttpRequestFactory());
    }
}
```

Comment: The question seems weird. Using `apache-async-httpclient` with `RestTemplate` in a blocking config. Why do you want to mix those 2 so much? Btw, from Spring 6 you should use WebClient anyways...

Comment: no for blocking config i am using httpcomponent config which i have shared in question. But I wanted to know how to configure the apache async http-client (non-blocking), I am asking this question as HttpComponentsAsyncClientHttpRequestFactory is now not there as part of new spring boot version.

Comment: I'll rephrase: Why don't you use WebClient that is already async? Why do you want to use RestTemplate?

Comment: yeah i know webclient, just wanted to know is there support exists for rest-template. It is just for learning purpose